# ERROR SyntaxError: Invalid RegExp: Invalid escape, js engine: hermes i am using marked to convert markdown to html

Tags: javascript, react-native

i want to convert markdown to html and none of the packages seems to be working. i am buidling an app in react native

i tried react-markdown, marked, react-native-htmlview none of them worked,  ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'marked' of undefined

This error is located at:
in ArticlePage (created by SceneView)
in StaticContainer
in EnsureSingleNavigator (created by SceneView)
in SceneView (created by SceneView)
in RCTView (createdby

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.